# Does a story like this even exist in islam? Im going crazy

Tags: quran, hadith

I've heard about a story of 2 tribes or families smth like this where they derived from 2 brother which parted ways. One of the tribes had beautiful women and ugly men while the other had beautiful men and ugly women. I don't remember clearly but they were not allowed to mix with together. Allah allowed the shaitan to misguide them as a test so shaitan made music and had parties from a tribe to attract the others on the other tribe. This is how music instruments and music was invented.

Comment: Probably a self-made tale by your elders to teach you good and bad manners. Quite common but extremely bad practice it is.

Answer (score 0):

There is no authentic story of this sort in any Islamic source I know.

Answer (score 0):

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته
Yes, I know the story you mean. First, there is no hadith was mentioned about this story. Rather, some Muslim scholars mentioned it to warn against it, and the source of the story is unknown.